# Not printing the body of blog post?

Tags: php, mysql

In my code, it should print the body of "Testing... Test Link", though it does not.
You can view the errors here: http://pirates-online-rewritten.com/blog.php?ID=1
This is my code:

```
<?php
include "header.php";
include "connect.php";
$ID = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(stripslashes($_GET['ID'])));
$getPost = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Blogs WHERE ID='$ID'");
$gP = mysql_fetch_object($getPost);

echo $gp->Body;

include "footer.php";
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Notice: Undefined variable: gp in /home/induadmi/public_html/por/blog.php on line 8
```

$gp doesn't exist. However $gP exists. Could they actually be the same ? :)